# MainActivity class not generated in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, src, main-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

Every since I updated Eclipse with the SDK manager to 23.0.1245622 when I go to make a new Andorid Application Project it won't generate the MainActivity in the SRC file. I have researched my issue and have tried uninstalling and reinstalling every, also I have added the https://dl.google.com/android/eclipse/ to the software sources with no avail. I am at a loss for finding a solution. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I had also same problem.
Solution: When creating the new android application, select "empty activity" instead of "blank activity". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create it by yourself.
Create a class, extends from android Activity, add your activity to Android manifest and add this inside activity tag:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Now you have a main activity =].

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. Load the Version before and work with that. create the project then update.

Comment: How would I go about loading an older version?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

create a new android project, uncheck Create Activity in step-2 (Config project).

and create MainActivity manually.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse higher version (api level 19), By default the MainActivity extends FragmentActivity... So firstly your Activity should be extends Activity and remove all the methods of FragmentActivity except Activity lifecycle methods.  May be your problem get solved.